# How to let AssertTrue indicate why a test failed like AssertEquals?

Tags: java, junit, tdd

**AssertEquals**

```
assertEquals(5,assignment.getAssignment());
```

results in:

```
Running tests
Test running started
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<5> but was:<1       1       1       1       1       >
at com.it030.numbersequences.AssignmentTest.testAssignmentAndPossibleAnswers(AssignmentTest.java:12)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1729)
```

and it is clear what went wrong.

---

**AssertTrue**

```
Assert.assertTrue(assignment.getAssignment().replaceAll("\\s", "")
    .matches("^1(1((1){3}|235)|361015)$"));
```

results in:

```
Running tests
Test running started
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at com.it030.numbersequences.AssignmentTest.testAssignmentAndPossibleAnswers(AssignmentTest.java:14)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1729)
```

and it is unclear what went wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Title has been updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All assert* methods have a variant where you can add a String that is displayed when the test fails.

So just use this one to add a message with more context about the failure.

```
 public static void assertTrue(String message,
                          boolean condition)
```

Example:

```
String replaced = assignment.getAssignment().replaceAll("\\s", "");
String msg = replaced+" does not match regexp ^1(1((1){3}|235)|361015)$";
Assert.assertTrue(msg , replaced
      .matches("^1(1((1){3}|235)|361015)$"));
```

results in:

```
Running tests
Test running started
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 2461016 does not match regexp ^1(1((1){3}|235)|361015)$
at com.it030.numbersequences.AssignmentTest.testAssignmentAndPossibleAnswers(AssignmentTest.java:18)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1729)
```